# Замена элемента на странице с помощью jq

Tags: jquery

Добрый вечер!

Скрипт пересчитывает общую сумму корзины при изменении количество товара.

```
<script>
$('#minus<?=$arItem["ID"]?>').click(function(){ // При клике на минус
price=$("#current_price_<?=$arItem["ID"]?>").html();//берем цену единицы товара
bas = $(".bx-soa-cart-d")[2].innerHTML;//берем текущую общую стоимость корзины
pricen=parseFloat( price.replace(' ','') );//приводим значение вида 1 234.56 руб. к числу
basn=parseFloat( bas.replace(' ','') );//приводим значение вида 1 234.56 руб. к числу
basket=basn-pricen;//вычисляем новую общую стоимость корзины
basket2=Intl.NumberFormat().format(basket)+" руб.";// приводим число к виду 1 234.56 руб. 
})
</script>
```

Как заменить старую сумму корзины на новую на странице, чтобы ее увидел пользователь?
Пробовал:

```
$($(".bx-soa-cart-d")[2].innerHTML).replaceWith( basket2 );
```

И:

```
$($(".bx-soa-cart-d")[2].innerHTML).html(basket2);
```

Не получается. Подскажите, в чем ошибка?

Comment: Покажите полный код. То есть, весь код вместе с тем, где вы пытаетесь вставить новую сумму

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var basket2 = 'Новая сумма';
$(".bx-soa-cart-d")[0].innerHTML = basket2;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bx-soa-cart-d">Старая сумма</div>
```

Comment: Уточню, надо на странице заменить старую сумму на новую.

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛяхов так а в чем проблема?

Comment: По нажатию кнопки старая сумма должна пересчитываться и пользователь должен ее видеть. На странице нужно заменить значение $(".bx-soa-cart-d")[2].innerHTML на высчитанное значение basket2

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛяхов так вы внимательнее посмотрите мой пример. Изначально на странице в блоке написано "Старая сумма", а после выполнения кода - "Новая сумма". Только у вас "новая сумма" будет высчитываться из вашего скрипта. И вместо моего `[0]`, поставьте свой `[2]`

Comment: Да, сумма меняется, спасибо!

Comment: Еще вопрос, с помощью Intl.NumberFormat() можно привести число к виду 1[пробел]234.56 ? После пересчета у меня получается либо 1[пробел]234,56 + пробовал ""en-US" - тогда получается 1,234.56

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛяхов по работе с Intl можно прочитать [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/intl)  - там все возможные форматы описаны